# Azure Durable Functions, Cannot access entity state from activity

Tags: javascript, azure, serverless, azure-durable-functions

While using Azure Durable functions and attempting to learn it I have created an orchestrator that is going to read a state of an entity, and then call other activities to perform other logic after. Pretty straightforward I thought.

Inside the orchestrator, it can read and see the entity. everything works fine. It calls the follow on activity as normal. Inside the activity I cannot read the state that the orchestrator just read?

here is the orchestrator

```
const df = require("durable-functions");

module.exports = df.orchestrator(function* (context) {
  context.log("MsgOrch started ");
  let incomingMessage = context.df.getInput();
  const entityId = new df.EntityId("", `1`);
  const lockState = yield context.df.callEntity(entityId, "get");

  if('fromApi' in incomingMessage){
    yield context.df.callActivity("Unlock", incomingMessage); //unlock the activity, need to call the activity to send the message through the websocket
  }
  else if(lockState.isLocked && lockState.lockHolder === incomingMessage.localEmail){
      yield context.df.callEntity(entityId, "update");
  }else if (!lockState.isLocked){
    yield context.df.callActivity("Lock", incomingMessage);
  }

});
```

the entity

```
const df = require("durable-functions");

module.exports = df.entity(function (context) {
  context.log(`Hello ${context.df.entityKey}!`)
  context.log(context.bindings);
  let currentValue = context.df.getState(newLockedObject);
  switch (context.df.operationName) {
    case "get":
      context.df.return(currentValue);
      break;
    case "lock":
      context.df.setState({
        locked: true,
        lockHolder: 'jim',
        seconds: getEpochSeconds(),
      });
      break;
    case "unlock":
      context.df.setState({
        locked: false,
        lockHolder: null,
      });
      break;
      case "update":
        currentValue.seconds = getEpochSeconds();
        context.df.setState(currentValue);
        break;
  }
});
```

and the activity that is called by the orchestrator.

```
 const df = require("durable-functions");
module.exports = async function (context) {
  const client = df.getClient(context);
  const entityId = new df.EntityId("lockedstate", `1`);
  const lockState = await client.readEntityState(entityId);
  context.log(lockState);
  return `Locked ${context.bindings.incomingMessage.id}!`;
};
```

state of the program while at the start of the if statement in the orchestrator
[image]

then the state of the program within the "lock" activity
[image]

according to the documentation at

`readEntityState` should read the same state as the orchestrator correct?

I've tried changed the identifiers of the Entity ID from something dynamically created from the input from the HTTPtrigger to something that as you can see I have just hard coded.

Been touring through the documentation on the Azure site but I seem to be implementing this correctly?

when I created the tutorial counter project they had it was working just fine.